# PostgreSQL - Trigger on INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I wan't to add a trigger in a `PostgreSQL` database. This trigger is used to concatenate values of 2 columns to update a 3rd one. I wan't to run it when a row is inserted or updated in the table.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILE(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FOLDER TEXT, NAME TEXT, URL TEXT);
```

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LINK() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    UPDATE FILE
    SET URL = CONCAT(FOLDER, NAME)
    WHERE ID = OLD.ID;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    UPDATE FILE   
    SET URL = CONCAT(FOLDER, NAME)
    WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_LINK
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON FILE
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE LINK();
```

When I insert a value in table like

```
INSERT INTO FILE VALUES (1, 'C:\', 'doc.pdf');
```

I have an error message `list index out of range` because `ID` number is not yet created and `UPDATE` query on `INSERT` can't execute. But if I make an `AFTER UPDATE` it will run infinitely.

How to run a trigger function on `INSERT` or `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` clause on `ID` to target only inserted or updated row ? I'm using `PostgreSQL 10.14`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use UPDATE to do that. Just assign the value. Also, a BEFORE trigger should not return `null` because that will abort the operation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LINK() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
  new.url := CONCAT(new.FOLDER, new.NAME);
  RETURN new; --<< important!
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: All right, I understand know. Simple and efficient solution